# The use of "be" in future tense in this sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

> I would like to visit NY in future if you are also there.

Is this a correct sentence? I am concerned about the "are" part.

Answer (score 3):

I'd guess that what you are trying to say is that you would like to visit NY, if at the time that you visit the other person will also be there. If so, what you should say is, "I would like to visit NY in the future, if you will also be there."

The sentence you have written is grammatically valid (except that you should say "the future", not just "future", but that's not your question). But it doesn't make much logical sense. Taken literally, it means, "I would like to visit NY in the future, if you are in New York now." It's possible that you mean that, but unlikely.

It would make perfect sense to use this combination of tenses in other cases. Like, "I would like to buy a model XYZ cell phone in the future, if you have one." That is, if you have one now, I would like to buy one some day.

Comment: I found out recently that UK English does use the phrase "in future". However, I do not think that it applies in this case. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2005/do-in-future-and-in-the-future-imply-different-meanings Perhaps a native speaker of UK English could clarify...

Comment: @Tashus It's certainly possible that UK usage is different. I yield on this to anyone knowledgeable on the subject.

Comment: Let me rephrase the sentence. It's not about the future part. "I would like to visit NY next weekend if you will also be there."

Comment: Same thing. Yes, this sentence is fine and makes sense. "I would like to visit NY next weekend if you are there" is unlikely, for the same reasons.

Comment: @Jay - I agree it's a bit unlikely, although we could tweak the wording and come up with something a bit more plausible, such as: _I would like to meet you in New York next weekend, if you happen to still be there._.

Answer (score 1):

This depends.

Is your friend in New York already and you plan to meet him there?

Or are you planning to visit New York and you are asking your friend to visit the city with you?

In the first case, say:

> "I would like to visit New York in the future if you are there."

In the second case, say:

> "I would like to visit New York in the future if you will go with me."